# PSQL Select 1 record every 10 minutes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database where I have data inserted every minute, and I'm looking to pull out the record for every 10 minute interval:

Example:
I have data from 9:00 to 5:00 with 1 record every minute, I want to pull out 9:10, 9:20, 9:30, 9:40, etc.

Right now I have:

```
select * from main where date = '2016-06-02' and time > '09:00:00' and time < '17:00:00'
```

This pulls all the records, but I want to limit it to only 10 minute intervals.

Comment: Can you show a little sample of your data, please?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring it out at least somewhat

```
select * from main where date = '2016-06-02' and and time > '09:00:00' and time < '17:00:00' and  time::varchar like '%:%0:%';
```

Comment: IMO the more right way is `... and extract(minutes from time)::int % 10 = 0`

Answer (score 1):

Another method, just for fun ...

```
select *
from   main
where date in (
        select generate_series(timestamp '2016-06-02 09:00:00', 
                               timestamp '2016-06-02 16:50:00',
                               '10 minute'::interval));
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with the query below. My date column is called `ts`.
What this query does is to first group every row in 5min buckets, order them by `ts`, and grab the first one.
For 10mins, replace 300 with 600.

```
select distinct on (CAST (extract(epoch from date_trunc('second', ts)) AS integer) / 300) ts
   ts, CAST (extract(epoch from date_trunc('second', ts)) AS integer) % 300 as sec,
   col_a, col_b


from main
where ts > '2020-02-25'

order by CAST (extract(epoch from date_trunc('second', ts)) AS integer) / 300 asc, ts asc

limit 500;
```